# how to add style a string in a method in .net

Tags: .net

I need to  add color to the section between the  + sings.  Could I wrap it in a span

`ServicesCountLabelProperty.Text = "Report will contain " + (this.FilterHashCount.ServicesCount == 0 ? "0" : (string.Format("{0:0,0}", this.FilterHashCount.ServicesCount)).TrimStart(Convert.ToChar("0"))) + " errors(s).";`

Comment: is this a label or a textbox ?

Comment: it renders in a label

Comment: `....<font color=red>red text</font>....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in a span and then you can style than span in any way you want.

```
string innerSpan = "<span class='someClass'>" + 
(this.FilterHashCount.ServicesCount == 0 ? "0" : 
(string.Format("{0:0,0}", this.FilterHashCount.ServicesCount)).TrimStart(Convert.ToChar("0"))) + 
"</span>" ;

ServicesCountLabelProperty.Text = "Report will contain " + innerSpan + "errors(s)."
```